# Combobox selected event auto trigger when programatically bind the datasource c#

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a stupid problems here, but I can't solve it. The problem is when I programatically bind the combobox with data it will auto set selectedItem but I use the property field to add items it will not set the selectedItem.

My question is how can I bind the items programatically without trigger the selected event (means it behaves like bind using the properties which do not set the selectedItem by default)? Thanks in advance.

**Example set programatically**

string[] items = {"Apple", "Orange", "Banana"};
comboBox1.DataSource = items;

When the program run it will look like this (**default value is selected which is Apple**):

[image]

**Example set items using properties field (VS 2013)**

[image]

Then it will look like this (**default value is not selected**):

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could unsubscribe and then subscribe to the event, as I think when you set the data using property field in the VisualStudio, all the settings will be applied before you have the event subscribed.

```
//unsubscribe the event handler (change the name of the event handler to your real name)
ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged -= ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged

//do your initialization
string[] items = {"Apple", "Orange", "Banana"}; 
comboBox1.DataSource = items;
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;

//subscribe to it again
ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged
```

Answer (score 0):

Write ComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1
This will solve your problem

Comment: I try this before, it does not work for me. It still trigger the selectedIndexChanged event

Comment: Try SelectionchangeCommited event.

Comment: Ok, it works for not triggering the event, but it still display the value at the comboxBox. I think this is not what I want. Anyway, Thanks you @Palak Maheria

Comment: To stop displaying first item in the combo box you can use ComboBox.SelectedIndex = - 1

Answer (score 0):

What if instead of writng this:

```
string[] items = {"Apple", "Orange", "Banana"}; 
comboBox1.DataSource = items;
```

you will write this:

```
string[] items = {"Apple", "Orange", "Banana"};
//comboBox1.Items.Clear();
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(items);
```